# Oracle -> Changing a column of a table automatically

Tags: oracle, plsql

is there anyway we can change a value of a column automatically base on a date? like writing a 
procedure or trigger?. I need the value to change without insert or updating any other table/column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not directly, no.

You can submit a job using either `DBMS_JOB` or `DBMS_SCHEDULER` that will run in the background and issue an `UPDATE` at a future point in time.  You can submit the job from a trigger when the row is inserted or updated, i.e.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
  l_jobno PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  IF :new.status = 'active'
  THEN 
    dbms_job.submit( l_jobno,
                     q'{UPDATE table_name SET status = 'inactive' WHERE table_id = }' || :new.table_id,
                     sysdate + x ); 
  END IF;
END;
```

Of course, depending on the number of rows we're talking about, you are probably better served having a single job that runs every few minutes that updates the table based on a whatever criteria you define.

Comment: @ Justin, what i meant is that the value will change itself w/o the need to do any update or insert. Eg. the value will change from "active" to "inactive" after x amount of days have passed